# How to increase decimal precision with 'exotic' functions?

Tags: python, decimal, cmath

I can't figure out how to specify my decimal precision for logs, importing decimal and setting the context does not affect the log functions.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 54

print(Decimal(197)/ Decimal(83))
2.37349397590361445783132530120481927710843373493975904

print(math.log(Decimal(197)))
5.2832037287379885
```

I would like to set a high precision for functions other than fractions. Python 3 btw.

Comment: The moment you touch a `Decimal` with anything from the `math` module, it degrades into a `float`.  If you want to keep your precision, you have to restrict yourself to methods and functions from `Decimal` - fortunately, this include a `.ln()` method, which returns 5.28320372873798850677979732916283097500864406235803971 for your example.

Comment: As shown in the answer below, `Decimal(math.log(197)) = 5.28320372873798849155946300015784800052642822265625`, but `print(f'{math.log(197):.050f}') = 5.28320372873798849155946300015784800052642822265625` too.

Comment: If you don't *need* base-10 rounding, just higher precision, consider using `gmpy2`.

Comment: There's a third-party module named [`mpmath`](https://pypi.org/project/mpmath/) that will allow you to do arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Possible solutions:

### String formatting:

- f-strings have the benefit of not requiring another package to be imported
- [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- Extend the decimal places shown, to the same extent as the `decimal` module

```
x = 4567.09710599898797936589076897
y = 2445.89790870380808990080797897
```

#### Lengthen:

```
print(f'{(x/y):.054f}')
>>> 1.867247643389702504990168563381303101778030395507812500

calculation = math.log(197)
print(f'{calculation:.050f}')
>>> 5.28320372873798849155946300015784800052642822265625
```

#### Shorten:

```
print(f'{(x/y):.02f}')
>>> 1.87
```

### `numpy`:

- [`numpy.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html)

#### Shorten:

```
print(np.round(x/y, 2))
>>> 1.87
```

#### Lengthen:

- `numpy` does not extend the precision shown, beyond what's shown by python.

```
print(np.around(x/y, 54))
>>> 1.8672476433897025

print(x/y)
>>> 1.8672476433897025
```

### `decimal` Module:

- [Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)

#### Example from the question:

```
print(math.log(197))
>>> 5.2832037287379885

print(math.log(Decimal(197.0)))
>>> 5.2832037287379885

print(Decimal(math.log(197)))
>>> 5.28320372873798849155946300015784800052642822265625

print(Decimal(197).ln())
>>> 5.283203728737988506779797329

print(f'{math.log(197):.050f}')
>>> 5.28320372873798849155946300015784800052642822265625
```

### Notes:

- Either method can be used to format the number to the required decimal place, prior to writing into a log.
- Caveat: due to the way numbers are represented in computers, I'm doubtful if increasing the number of decimal places shown, increases the precision.

  - [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)
- Using `f-strings` provided the same final output precision as using the `decimal` module.

Comment: This is good for rounding, but (as I edited in to clarify) I am actually looking to get more precision.

Comment: @user7778287 apparently f-strings work for shortening or lengthening